# Problem involving subspaces and linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

I'm asking for some opinions about my proof!

$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces, and $T : V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation. $Z$ is a subspace of $W$, and $U$ is the set of all $\textbf{x} \in V$ such that $T(\textbf{x}) \in Z$. Show that $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

1. $\textbf{0}$ is in $U$ since $T$ is a linear transformation (the matrix $A$ of $T$ will have the trivial solution).
2. Take $\textbf{x}_1$ and $\textbf{x}_2$ from $U$. Since $T(\textbf{x}_1+\textbf{x}_2) = T(\textbf{x}_1)+T(\textbf{x}_2)$, we have that $\textbf{x}_1+\textbf{x}_2$ also lies in $U$.
3. Take $\textbf{x}$ from $U$ and a scalar $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $T(c \textbf{x}) = c T(\textbf{x})$, we also have that $c\textbf{x}$ lies in $U$.

Because of these steps, $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

I honestly think that this is pretty "abstract", so I don't know if I right here...

Comment: Looks pretty good to me!

Comment: you can actually combine steps 2 and 3 and say since $T(c_1\mathbf{x}_1+c_2\mathbf{x}_2)=c_1T(\mathbf{x}_1)+c_2T(\mathbf{x}_2)$...

Comment: Thanks! Then I'm pleased with myself. :-) Yes, I also se that i could combine step 2 and 3... nice. :-)

Comment: It's not necessary, but that one step does the trick.  I never used to do that and my professor at the time always did and it always seemed better to just get it all at once with the linear combination.

Comment: I guess "your way" is more efficient, and "my way" is from the textbook because of pedagogical  purposes perhaps. :-)